# Planks along a surface using Sverchok

Tags: procedural, sverchok

I'm trying to recreate this concept art

[image]

and i'm having trouble recreating this bit, this dome made of planks

[image]

Making it by hand, using, for example, lattice to curve a premade stretch of planks, seems like a waste of time and effort as this seems exactly the sort of job for sverchok, houdini or any other procgen software.

Am i right in thinking so? Can this be done with sverchok? Perhaps first modeling the dome roof as just a shape and then generating planks on it? If so, i would greatly appreciate any links, help or just pointers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

1. Try example *points on mesh* in lines  it will give you some kind of
   lines.
2. than follow orientation algorithm, creating *matrices* based on
   three points -

   - (0,0,0),
   - first vertex of an edge
   - second vertex of an edge.
     [image]
3. on top - make planks (length can be the length of an edge)  and
   texturize them

[image]

[image]

Comment: офигеть, редко когда получаешь ответ от самого разработчика. I should've mentioned that i know how parametric modeling works in principle, on practice, i am very much a novice. Can you give me any links that would enable me to understand what you've written? At any rate, thanks a lot for the answer!